# Do we need a separate tag for Pathfinder 2e Remastered?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonymization

Paizo is re-releasing content for its Pathfinder Second Edition system, labeling it a "[Remaster](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/corepreview)". There are significant differences in content, both in how its present and the actual effects of various rules elements.

Do we need to create a [pathfinder-2r], [pathfinder-2.5], or similar tag to differentiate between questions about the original rules published vs. the new content? Should it be a synonym of [pathfinder-2e]?

Comment: Related: [Do we need a separate tag for D&D 5e 2024?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12506/do-we-need-a-separate-tag-for-dd-5e-2024)

Answer (score 10):

### Yes

While they are significant overlap in certain rules, and the systems are compatible "in theory", there are different versions of the same spell and/or rule in both systems, so we'll need clarity as to what system we are discussing. Some tables (like mine) will continue with the pre-Remaster rules (because we're playing a pre-Remaster AP with pre-Remaster characters and I own pre-Remaster books). This reminds me a bit of things DnD 3e vs 3.5e, or Pathfinder 1 vs DnD 3.5e.

### My Tag Proposal

I have a couple ideas, but my preference is to keep in sync with Archive of Nethys's plan (since we reference them often and they're the official SRD). Their plan was unveiled on the August 3rd 2023 update (scroll down here: https://2e.aonprd.com).

My preference:

- Create tags [pathfinder-2e legacy] & [pathfinder-2e remaster].
- Mark most/all existing PF2e questions with [pathfinder-2e legacy]
- Alias [pathfinder-2e remaster] to [pathfinder-2e].

We can then go through the old questions marked with "legacy" and tag them with [pathfinder-2e] if they aren't legacy specific questions.

The usage pattern would be:

- Use [pathfinder-2e] for questions that aren't specifically about legacy
- Use [pathfinder-2e legacy] for questions that are about **legacy exclusive things**, like alignment.
- Have [pathfinder-2e remaster] alias to [pathfinder-2e] to instill that the Remaster is the current default and so users who are unsure which tag to use (Remaster or plain) will be helped.

Comment: I think it’s a bit premature to be trying to nail down the tag. I think it makes more sense to just pick a placeholder tag for the remaster, and see how the broader community comes around to referring the different rule sets.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov sounds like an answer to me, more than a comment ;)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov regardless, it's technically a little premature but Remaster source books are already being released - the Rage of Elements book uses Remaster rules. The Remaster core books haven't dropped yet, but we're already in the Remaster era. So I think Ifusaso is right to ask right about now so we can nail something down. If we don't act soon, we'll lose the ability to easily tag current questions with the legacy tag. (Arguably we already have, but there haven't been too many Rage of Elements questions).

Comment: The Remaster Player and GM Core are also shipping, and PDF's have been sent to the subscription members.

Comment: I don't use Meta often; what kind of window should we leave for additional answer(s), and do we commit the changes or let the mods do so?

Comment: tagging @nitsua60 for Ifusaso's question - I'm in the same boat as Ifusaso, figure you might know the answer

Comment: I worry about the amount of churn this would generate, updating most of 800+ questions twice to cause no change ([pathfinder-2e] -> [pathfinder-2e legacy] -> [pathfinder-2e]). Inverting the strategy to something like, "We go through the old questions marked with "pathfinder-2e" and tag them with [pathfinder-2e legacy] if they are legacy specific questions." seems much less noisy for the same or less amount of effort.

Comment: @brandon I'm fine with that approach as well, and you're right that that should be less noisy!

Comment: SO, first off, I agree with this as an overall way of handling things. The correct answer is not so much "Do we need a new tag for the remaster" (Emphatically, **no**), but rather, that we **do** need a new tag to identify out of date/legacy content that is no longer up to date. On a related note, I just hopped over to Meta to ask whether we should persue a similar cleanup for the [Pathfinder-2e-Playtest] tag. It might be worth starting up a new Meta question for a larger PF2e tag cleanup project.

Answer (score 0):

### No

While the Pathfinder Second Edition Remaster Project does include various changes to some of the original rules, it's not described as a new edition and doesn't warrant a new tag for applicable questions and answers. Instead, reprinted rules should be treated as any other errata for a system and addressed contextually based on the specific question/answer.

To quote the game's publisher Paizo's [blog](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo6siae?Pathfinder-Second-Edition-Remaster-Project) on the subject:

> Today, we are pleased to reveal the Pathfinder Second Edition Remaster Project, four new hardcover rulebooks that offer a fresh entry point to the Pathfinder Second Edition roleplaying game! The first two books, *Pathfinder Player Core* and *Pathfinder GM Core*, release this November, with *Pathfinder Monster Core* (March 2024) and *Pathfinder Player Core 2* (July 2024) completing the remastered presentation of Pathfinder’s core rules. The new rulebooks are compatible with existing Pathfinder Second Edition products, incorporating comprehensive errata and rules updates as well as some of the best additions from later books into new, easy-to-access volumes with streamlined presentations inspired by years of player feedback.
>
> ...
>
> **Is this a new edition of Pathfinder?**
>
> No. The Pathfinder Second Edition Remaster Project does not change the fundamental core system design of Pathfinder. Small improvements and cosmetic changes appear throughout, but outside of a few minor changes in terminology, the changes are not anywhere substantive enough to be considered a new edition. We like Pathfinder Second Edition. You like Pathfinder Second Edition. This is a remastered version of the original, not a new version altogether.

This is distinct from the case with D&D 3.5 as an update to D&D 3.0, where the new books were marketed as version 3.5 of the rules. "Remaster" is never even mentioned in the new Pathfinder *Player Core* or *GM Core* books outside of a credited "Remaster Development Team".

Having a new tag for the remastered rules might become confusing because of this, with future Pathfinder 2e readers not knowing their books are updated versions of original books wholly replaced:

> In time, the *Pathfinder Player Core*, *Pathfinder GM Core*, *Pathfinder Monster Core*, and *Pathfinder Player Core 2* will replace the *Pathfinder Core Rulebook*, *Gamemastery Guide*, *Bestiary*, and *Advanced Player’s Guide*, which Paizo will not reprint once their current print runs expire. Existing Pathfinder players should be assured that the core rules system remains the same, and the overwhelming majority of the rules themselves will not change. Your existing books are still valid. The newly formatted books consolidate key information in a unified place—for example, *Pathfinder Player Core* will collect all the important rules for each of its featured classes in one volume rather than spreading out key information between the *Core Rulebook* and the *Advanced Player’s Guide*.

Answer (score -1):

[pathfinder-2e-remaster](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder-2e-remaster) comes to mind, as that is how it is advertized.