# Do we need a separate tag for D&D 5e 2024?

Tags: discussion, tags, dungeons-and-dragons, synonymization

Wizards of the Coast is releasing a replacement *Player's Handbook*, *Dungeon Master's Guide*, and *Monster Manual* for its Dungeons & Dragons Fifth Edition system, labeling them the **2024 Core Rulebooks**. ["There will be many fundamental updates to D&D"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/1310-faq-one-d-d-2024-core-rulebooks-d-d-digital-and) as part of this new release. There are ["updates and improvements to the classes, mechanics, items, and monsters."](https://dndstore.wizards.com/us/product/820944/planescape-adventures-in-the-multiverse-digital-plus-physical-bundle#:%7E:text=2024%20AND%20BEYOND)

Do we need to create a [dnd-5e2024], [dnd-5.2e] (or whatever point-version the 2024 SRD gets), or similar tag to differentiate between questions about the original rules published vs. the new content? Should it be a synonym of [dnd-5e]?

Comment: Related: [Do we need a separate tag for Pathfinder 2e Remastered?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12504/do-we-need-a-separate-tag-for-pathfinder-2e-remastered)

Answer (score 8):

Let’s wait until we have a question about it to have this conversation, or at least until we’re close enough to release to know a great deal more about the content. You don’t just create tags here. You first ask a question, then tag it appropriately. If the question you have asked really ought to have a tag that doesn’t exist yet, that’s the point at which we would create that tag. We don’t have any questions about it yet, and there aren’t really any questions you could ask yet that would need a new D&D edition tag, so this meta discussion is altogether premature. But when I think we know enough about the game to be able to meaningfully have a discussion about this, I’ll delete this answer and post a new one. But that will probably be sometime in 2024.

And while we’re on the topic, this meta discussion is still very relevant today: [WotC announced that a "new evolution" of D&D will be coming in 2024. Is it too soon to pose and answer questions about it?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11946/62294).